# How to access and find OneDrive files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, onedrive

I'm trying to post my question here because I'm stuck.

After multiple searches, I can't find an up-to-date method to access my OneDrive files online.
I don't want redirection because it's a background task.
What is described on this page does not seem to suit me :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#token-flow

Has anyone found a simple, up-to-date way to access their OneDrive files?

thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean your statement of `does not seem to suit me`? Why it doesn't suit you? We cannot help you, because your description of problem seems abstract or subjective without further explanation.

Comment: Your question's wording is not very clear, but are you really asking how to authenticate with the Graph API without user interaction? If so then read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service